# How can I use adb shell command in android?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I want use adb shell cammand in android.
My goal is show **"adb shell pm list packages -f" result** on android( just print that result )

I think it is only one solution.. is there any other solution on my problem?

I want just print that result( packages list )..!

Comment: Are you using android studio ?

Comment: Start terminal and write `pm list packages -f`.

Comment: @MilindVyas yes I am

Comment: ok thats great now open terminal you got terminal where it is?

Comment: @MilindVyas um... yes

Comment: you can find it nearby android monitor tab below of studio

Comment: just paste your your code in it adb shell pm list packages -f . and it will show you each packages in your phone or emulator

Comment: my questions is how can i print the result on my phone screen.. not my android studio..!